# Indent a full paragraph using CSS

Tags: html, css, indentation, product

I wanted to type a description of a product next to an image. The description-text should be indented. I tried `margin-left: 30px;`, but this didn't work.

How can I indent the full paragraph?

html:

```
<main>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="/assets/img/AVRStick.png">
            <h1>USB MF - Board</h1>
            <span class="title">description</span>
            <br>
            <p class="content">The USB MF - Board is an Arduino compatible, minimalistic and cheap AVR microprocessor board with USB interface.</p>
            </li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

css:

```
main {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 15px);
    background: #ffffef;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

li {
    overflow: auto;
}

img {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 60px;
}

.title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set some width like 250px and float it left

```
.content{
text-align: justify;
margin-left: 30px;
width: 250px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Did you count for me the perfect width (250px) to get the full width of the main element?

Comment: I tested and it looks good :) and I would add some margin top maybe 15px

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done with html with this method.

```
<p class="content" style="padding-left:40px;"> your paragraph </p>
```

Just set padding to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
    text-align: justify;
    float: right;
    width: 255px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.content{
    text-align: justify;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: P{lease explain *why* `float:` and `width:` are needed and why (if there is a reason) you dropped `text-align:`.